# conversion of xpt to csv

Tags: python, sas

Code to convert `xpt` files to `csv` in Python Google `colab` platform.

Code:

```
import xport 

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_sas("(/content/gdrive/MyDrive/home/P_DSQTOT.XPT)")

----

df = pd.read_sas(FILE_PATH + FILE + '.XPT', index=None)

df.to_csv(FILE_PATH + FILE + '.csv')

expect to convert `xpt` to csv
```

File code in Python in Google `colab` platform.

Comment: And what happens when you try either of those snippets?  You don't tell us the results.

Comment: Why do you have the parentheses inside the string in the first read_sas?  You might need to add a `+ '/' +`  between path and file in the second.